# unicode url path gets error 500 in django production server

Tags: django, url, unicode, wsgi, django-wsgi

I have "myproject" in django that is for mywebsite.com

I have url's such as **"mywebsite.com/path1"** that is working perfectly in both development (27.0.0.1:8000) and production server

I have url's such as **"mywebsite.com/مسیر۱"** that is working perfectly in development (27.0.0.1:8000) server but gets error 500 in production server

I have no idea what could be the problem. Any advice in this regard is highly appreciated

Further Explanation:

Here is the url pattern of the project:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('path1', myview_eng, name='myview_eng'),
    path('مسیر۱', myview_unicode, name='myview_unicode'),
]
```

and these are the views:

```
def myview_eng(request):
    return render(request, 'myview_eng.html', {})

def myview_unicode(request):
    return render(request, 'myview_unicode.html', {})
```

please note that "myview_eng.html" and "myview_unicode.html" are static pages

---

**Update:**

I sent a ticket to the company hosting my website and told them about the issue.

They replied:

" We have changed Unicode from iso to UTF8 in the WSGI Handler.

**You now should use the same Unicode as well**"

First of all, I do not understand the second part of their response.
Secondly, I now get a 404 error when opening **"mywebsite.com/مسیر۱"**

Any advice?

Comment: can your corresponding URL config?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu What do you mean? Please explain

Comment: @ArakkalAbu I added additional info